# How can I check is strings with characters that are not letters or number

Tags: java

I am trying to trim any characters that are before a-Z 0-9

but this doesn't work

I need `>&%Hell$o`  to become `Hell$o`

```
private String removeStartingCharacters(String linkName) {
    if(linkName.startsWith("^[a-Z0-9]")){
        try {
            linkName = linkName.substring(1);               
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return linkName;
        }
        return removeStartingCharacters(linkName);
    }else 
        return linkName;
}
```

Comment: Please define "doesn't work". (Note that `startsWith` doesn't take a regular expression...) I would suggest that a single call to `replaceAll` would be simpler here...

Comment: you need to use matches, no startsWith. Also please read the documentation, startsWith does not use a regex.

Comment: Did you look at the doc of `String` class? What does `startsWith` accept as parameter?

Comment: @JonSkeet it doesnt work as in it doesnt remove the starting characters. if startwith doesn't take regex, how can I do it?

Comment: @code578841441 He already gave you the answer.

Comment: @code578841441: Yes it does, if you use it correctly. You do need to use the right regex though... See my answer.

Comment: `a-Z` does not work because of the positions of `'a'` and `'Z'` in the code charts.  `[a-Z]` matches any character that is `>= 'a'` and `<= 'Z'`.  However, the characters are really just numbers, and `'a'` is 97 and `'Z'` is 90, so there are no characters in the range.  `[A-z]` also doesn't work because there are six characters in the range that aren't letters.  You'll need `[A-Za-z]` or a special regex construct that says "letter".  (In addition to using a method that actually uses regexes, which `startsWith` doesn't.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use `replaceFirst` to replace characters not contained within `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` re-adding underscore to remove that character

```
input = input.replaceFirst("^[\\W_]+", "");
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @War10ck How about now?

Answer (score 1):

you can just use `Character.isLetterOrDigit(char)`:

```
private String removeStartingCharacters(String linkName) {
    if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(linkName.cahrAt(0)){
        try {
            linkName = linkName.substring(1);               
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return linkName;
        }
        return removeStartingCharacters(linkName);
    } else 
        return linkName;
}
```

Comment: I'll take iterative approach, if not regex.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're after:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(trimStart("&%Hell$o"));
        // [ and ] are between A-Z and a-z...
        System.out.println(trimStart("[]Hell$o"));
        System.out.println(trimStart("Hell$o"));
    }

    private static String trimStart(String input) {
        // The initial ^ matches only at the start of the string
        // The [^A-Za-z0-9] matches all characters *except* A-Z, a-z, 0-9
        // The + matches at least one character. (The output is the same
        // as using * in this case, as if there's nothing to replace it would
        // just replace the empty string with itself...)
        return input.replaceAll("^[^A-Za-z0-9]+", "");
    }
}
```

(The output shows `Hell$o` in all cases.)

A single call to `replaceAll` is significantly simpler than what you're doing at the moment.

EDIT: `replaceFirst` will work too, but you *do* still need the `^` at the start to make sure it only replaces characters from the start of the string. The "first" in `replaceFirst` just means the first occurrence of the pattern, not the first characters within the input string. Use whichever method you find more readable.

Note that this *only* allows a-z, A-Z and 0-9 as your starting characters:

- It doesn't allow the characters between Z and a (e.g. `[` and `]`)
- It doesn't allow non-ASCII letters or digits

You'll need to adjust the regex if those rules don't match your actual requirements

Comment: replaceAll is not necessary and replaceFirst better expresses the OP's intent

Comment: @GeorgeJempty: Ah, hadn't thought of that. Will edit.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty: Actually, I'm not sure. Given that it's anchored to the start of the string - and has to be - I think it still makes sense to call it `replaceAll`. My first inclination on thinking about `replaceFirst` was to get rid of the initial `^`, and that would be incorrect. I don't think it really matters which is used, to be honest - neither `replaceAll` nor `replaceFirst` expresses "replace matching characters at the start of the string".

Answer (score 1):

A `Pattern`-based solution would be as such:

```
public static String removeStartingNonAlnums(String input) {
    // null check
    if (input == null) {
        return null;
    }
    // empty check
    else if (input.isEmpty()) {
        return "";
    }
    // pattern check
    else {
                              // | start of input
                              // | | negation of alpha-numeric category
                              // | |        | zero/more greedy quantifier
                              // | |        |   | replaces with empty
        return input.replaceAll("^\\P{Alnum}*", "");
    }

}
```

... wherein `">&%Hell$o"` becomes `Hell$o`.

Answer (score 1):

```
str.replaceFirst("^[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "");
```